# How to execute “if” statement only one time in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently scraping a web page and a certain variable `minute` is changed every few seconds. This `minute` is located inside a `def` which runs forever. How can I make it so if, for example, `minute == 80`, the if statement only runs once?

Here is how the code looks like:

```
def login(): # necesarry for this
// stuff
return r

def run(r):
    //stuff
    minute_soup = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"clock-period"})
    minute = minute_soup[0].text

    if minute == 80:
        print(minute)

    time.sleep(10)

r = login()
while True:
   run(r)
```

Currently, each time `minute` is equal to 80, it does the same thing over and over again, every 10 seconds until `minute` is not equal to 80. Is there any way for it to do it once when `minute` is equal to 80?

Comment: You can set a flag that you've already run it once? It's not really clear what you're asking from what you've described and shown so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the parameter to hold a flag:

```
def run(r):
    //stuff
    minute_soup = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"clock-period"})
    minute = minute_soup[0].text

    if minute == 80 and r.flag:
        r.flag = False
        print(minute)
    if minute != 80:
        r.flag = True

    time.sleep(10)

r = login()
r.flag = True
while True:
   run(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from your question you can use a `flag` and when first time minutes become `80` set it true then `if` will never execute again:

```
def login(): # necesarry for this
// stuff
return r

def run(r):
    //stuff
    minute_soup = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"clock-period"})
    minute = minute_soup[0].text
    flag = False

    if (minute == 80 and !flag):
        flag = True
        print(minute)

    time.sleep(10)

r = login()
while True:
   run(r)
```

Comment: You set `flag` to `false` (clue: this should be `False`) every time that `run()` is called, so I think this will suffer the problem that the OP reports.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
flag = true
def run(r):
    if r == 80:
        if flag:
            flag = false
            //More stuff
    else:
        flag = true
```

I suggest you look into eventhandling, because infinite-looping can usually be resolved by using events which results in cleaner code

Comment: I keep getting this error... help please? I've tried setting it as global but doesn't work. UnboundLocalError: local variable 'flag' referenced before assignment

Answer (score -1):

```
minuteRunOnce = False
def run(r):
    //stuff
    minute_soup = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"clock-period"})
    minute = minute_soup[0].text

    if (minute == 80 and not(minuteRunOnce)):
        print(minute)
        minuteRunOnce = True

    time.sleep(10)

r = login()
while True:
   run(r)
```